# LINQ to Entities: can't convert Lambda expression to type "string"

Tags: linq, entity-framework, include

My lambda expressions within the Include statements are getting the error in that I've included in the title of this post.  I do have a 'using.System.Linq' in my class.  What's up?  ~susan~

```
FVTCEntities db = new FVTCEntities();

public List<RESTAURANT> getRestaurants(string cuisineName)
{
    var cuisineID = db.CUISINEs.First(s => s.CUISINE_NAME == cuisineName).CUISINE_ID;

    List<RESTAURANT> result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include(x => x.CITY).Include(x => x.CUISINE) 
                               where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == cuisineID 
                               select RESTAURANT).ToList();

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF, the Include() method accepts a string as parameter. If you want it to accept Lambda Expressions, you should read the following post: http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/entity-framework-using-include-with-lambda-expressions/

Comment: I think in EF4.1, you will have the option to use Lamda expression, here is the post from ET team. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Are you using DBContext in EF4.1, based on [the blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) by the ET team, Include is an extension method in the System.Data.Entity namespace so make sure you are using that namespace.

Comment: This was the solution for me, using EF6. I wish this would have been marked as the correct solution, as it lead me to pass over this the first time. Thanks J.W.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx

I don't have a ton of experience with .Include(), but this seems to make sense.

maybe .Include("CITY").Include("CUISINE")